# Skylark struct with methods

Tags: struct, bazel, skylark, starlark

Here's something I tried to do, and it works well. I find it useful, but it feels like a hack, so I'm afraid it will break in the future.

I'm working on converting a large project to Bazel, and we have lots of local wrappers, something like:

```
my_cc_library(name='a', srcs=['lib.c'])
my_cc_binary(name='b', deps=['a'], srcs=['main.c'])
```

This requires lots of `load` commands, which are annoying and a repeating source of errors.
If it was normal Python, I'd simply import a whole module. But Skylark requires loading functions one by one.

I can remove the need for individual loads, using a struct.

In `my.bzl`:

```
def _my_cc_library(...): ...
def _my_cc_binary(...): ...

my = struct(cc_library=_my_cc_library, cc_binary=_my_cc_binary)
```

In various `BUILD` files:

```
load('//my.bzl', 'my')
my.cc_library(name='a', srcs=['lib.c'])
my.cc_binary(name='b', deps=['a'], srcs=['main.c'])
```

As I wrote above, it all works well. I can use if for wrappers to native rules, and for various other functions.

But an I abusing the language? Is it prone to break in the future?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is used in other places (e.g. https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/master/lib/collections.bzl), it's safe to use it.

Not all tools support it well, though. For example, you won't be able to update your BUILD files with [Buildozer](https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/blob/master/buildozer/README.md) - although it's something that can be fixed.

> This requires lots of `load` commands, which are annoying and a repeating source of errors.

I agree it's annoying. In the future, we should have better tooling for updating `load` lines (to automatically add/remove them).

Rules in BUILD files look like `my_cc_library(...)` due to historical reasons. For a long time, `load` didn't exist and all rules were hard-coded in Bazel. Maybe we should encourage the `my.cc_library(...)` syntax and make it easier to use.

Comment: Laurent, does Buildozer support this now? Is it easier to use this pattern?